# Request for counter examples in group theory

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, examples-counterexamples, big-list

I am looking to "collect" books, papers, or even webpages, that have interesting examples/counterexamples in group theory.

I imagine there will be a couple types of answers:

- A particular example which is an example of some interesting phenomena.
- A post on particular properties which contains examples and references to
- Answer tied together by a theme/construction which provides many examples―like (generalization) of small cancellation theory.

---

I am particularly interested in collecting sources with a focus on, infinite, finitely generated groups, but I am not restricting myself to these.

---

A sort of relevent question, on mathoverflow, is [Counterexamples in Algebra?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29006/counterexamples-in-algebra)

(I have somewhat widened the scope of the question so that this basically becomes the source I was originally looking for)

Comment: I am not sure, maybe this question would be better off asking for individual groups that are counter examples to a lot of things...

Comment: Do not know about webpages, but books and papers of this type, I think, simply do not exist. What you can find are books and papers describing constructions of groups with exotic properties, such as Olshansky's book.

Comment: One of the smaller "big-list" questions on this site. The list of Related questions on this page looks like a possible source.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That gave me a good chuckle. Maybe I should have made this page the source I was looking for rather than hoping there where outside sources.

Comment: @MoisheKohan You are right. I have decided to widen the scope of the question somewhat. I think a summary of what sort of examples *Geometry of Defining Relations in Groups* could make a great answer (the Tarski Monster is in there! That would be a great post by itself).